# Learning boost::regex, matching wildcards

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I've just started learning `regex`.

I need to match things like this:

```
hostname21.processName
```

The `.` is the anchor. Pre and post anchor are represented by `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but I'm not sure how to match *both* of the conditions on either side of the anchor.

I'm using `boost::regex` if that helps.

**EDIT**

I tried Jerry's code with `boost::regex reg("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+");` and it worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you mean something like that: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: its much better to learn using regexes using some kind of regex testing tool. Can even be notepad++ if you dont want to use notepad then google regex testing websites. boost uses perl styled regular expressions - they are quite popular. if you want match text u just specified u could even write ".*\\..*" - if you really want to match dot.

Comment: @AleksanderFular Notepad++ is actually a pretty decent idea, because it actually uses boost as it's regex engine (at least as of Notepad++ 6). And so does Sublime, I think.

Comment: @TylerJandreau note that when you are using Jerry's code, in C++ code, you'll probably have to double-escape the period. So as a string it would look like: `"[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"` And you might want to add (regex) anchors around the pattern like `"^...$"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reg("(\w)+\\.(\w)+")`